# How to get CA pem file content using PHP in server side that send through CURL

Tags: php, curl, openssl, pem

Anyone please tell me how we get the CA pem file content which send through PHP CURL CURLOPT_CAINFO parameter or certificated added postman, in server side[End point] using PHP

Please check blow sample code

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/certs/cabundle.pem");
  ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

In above code cabundle.pem contains certificate content. I need to fetch that content in end point ie.https://example.com/ server using PHP code.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: You asked this already, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758515/, and that was closed as “needs details or clarity”. So don’t just post the same thing again then.

Comment: It is really rather unclear, what you actually want to achieve here. You want system A to make an HTTP request to B - and then you expect B could somehow access the file system of A based on that, or … what?